# css overlap issue

Tags: html, css

Hi i have an issue with css as when the user not full fill the text box content properly an error message will appear below the contact us box, but it has overlap issue with the image below the contact us box.[image]

[image]

how can i prevent the image move along when the box expand?

the contact us form css is as follow

```
#contactusbox {
padding: 5px;
width: 310px;
height: auto;
float: right;
margin-top: 292px;
background-color: #E2E2E2;
border: 1px solid #B2B8B8;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #333;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want the image to move, or not to?

Comment: no..i want the expanded box overlap the image

Comment: doesn't it already? that's what I see in the image. can you explain better? also, are you talking about a different message? the one in the picture doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: let me add the entire screenshot

Comment: @djjeck now can you see the different?

Comment: For one, instead of floating it to the right, you could just use an absolute or fixed position with a larger z-index value than the rest of the page.

Comment: remove height:auto proerty and set a fix value for the height.

Answer (score 0):

Change position `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;`